# Testing Uber SignIn with Auth0

Tags: uber-api, auth0

I'm attempting to connect my uber app with a Auth0 signon.
And allow my users to sign on using their uber accounts.

When setting up and then trying the integration, 
I received the attached error...

[image]

I see this is the link that is being activated when pressing the try button within Auth0:

`bash
https://teamxna2.auth0.com/authorize/?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=aC7p8ZN4QVaBSq0HrQCa83yHBiAEhYoF&connection=uber&redirect_uri=https://manage.auth0.com/tester/callback?connection=uber`

So in the Uber App dashboard I changed my redirect uri to variations of...
`bash
https://manage.auth0.com/tester/callback?connection=uber
https://manage.auth0.com/tester/callback
https://manage.auth0.com`

But i'm still recieving errors...What should put as the redirect URI in uber dash
to try this integration?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following redirect_url: `https://teamxna2.auth0.com/login/callback`